# Исключение в конструкторе

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

Как известно если в конструкторе класса кидается исключение то объект не считается созданным и его деструктор не вызывается.

Рассмотрим такой класс:

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        void operator =(char* v)
        {
            _v = v;
        }
        ~B()
        {
            delete[] _v;
        }
    private:
        char* _v;
    };

    B _b;

public:
    A()
    {
        _b = new char[10];
         throw 1;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
   A a;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
  }
}
```

В этом случае утечки памяти не будет. Но почему будет вызван деструктор класса `B`? Откуда мы в него придем? Ведь объект его содержащий не будет разрушен.

Comment: Это объект класса `A` будет считаться не созданным, а объект класса `B`, являющийся полем создаваемого объекта класса `A`, будет уже создан. Соответственно при выбрасывании исключения из конструктора класса `A` будет вызван сгенерированный компилятором код для разрушения уже созданных полей класса `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но почему будет вызван деструктор класса B? Откуда мы в него придем?

Деструктор для поля `A::b` будет автоматически вызван конструктором класса `A` при возникновении исключения.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут

```
A()
{
    _b = new char[10];
```

раз вы не написали явный вызов конструктора для `b_`, будет вызван конструктор по умолчанию.

Можно было бы переписать этот кусок как

```
A():_b(new char[10])
{
```

конечно, написав соответствующий конструктор для `B`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка в сообщении, не конструктор а деструктор

Comment: А деструктор будет вызван, потому что был вызван конструктор! (О котором я написал - читай про конструктор по умолчанию).

Comment: Деструктор вызывается при выходе из области видимости, где это происходит?

Comment: Когда сгенерировано исключение, все созданные к этому времени в блоке try объекты уничтожаются. Все.

Answer (score 1):

Конструктор класса b будет вызван при вызове конструктора класса A, потому что нужно инициализировать переменные класса. А потом здесь `_b = new char[10];` будет вызван `operator=`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка в сообщении, не конструктор а деструктор

Comment: согласно стандарту языка с++, при выбросе исключения в конструкторе, будет происходить расскрутка стека, в процессе которой будут вызваны деструкторы переменных класса (ошибочно называемых "полями"), который бросил исключение.